# What are the differences between awaiting inside entity framework context and outside?

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-6

I am trying to run a SQL stored procedure in an async way in C#. I have found two options and I would like to understand the differences between the two:

I have to await before getting out of the using statement else the context would be disposed:

```
private async Task<List<Currency>> Test1Async()
{
    using (var dc = new LandmarkEntities())
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return dc.get_currencies()
            .Select(x => new Currency
            {
                ExchangeRate = x.exchange_rate,
                Mnemonic = x.mnemonic,
            })
            .ToList();
        });
    }
}
```

Or I return a running async task containing the entity framework context which will be awaited somewhere else:

```
private Task<List<Currency>> Test2Async()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var dc = new LandmarkEntities())
        {
            return dc
                .get_currencies()
                .Select(x => new Currency
                {
                    ExchangeRate = x.exchange_rate,
                    Mnemonic = x.mnemonic,
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    });
}
```

As `get_currencies()` is a stored procedure `.ToListAsync();` cannot be used.

Comment: How is `get_currencies()` defined? Is that a function you have written?  If so, can you post it?

Comment: It is a stored procedure defined in SQL

Answer (score 2):

You could use `.ToListAsync();`

```
private async Task<List<Currency>> Test2Async()
{
    using (var dc = new LandmarkEntities())
    {
        return await dc
            .get_currencies()
            .Select(x => new Currency
            {
                ExchangeRate = x.exchange_rate,
                Mnemonic = x.mnemonic,
            })
            .ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I do when I query tables, however it doesn't seem possible to do the same with stored procedures

Comment: This page: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx suggests using `.FromSQL()` rather than the function style you are using.